# How to display specific json values rather than print or dump function

Tags: php, json

using the following, I can display all information as an array in two formats, however I wish to assign a value to a variable and use e.g just the names rather than a complete screen dump.

> $url = 'http://myurl';
>
> $json = file_get_contents($url);
>
> $dump=(var_dump(json_decode($json, true)));
>
> $json_output = json_decode($json); print_r($json_output)

This is probably very easy, my apologies.

Comment: To clarify, you would like to access the individual values of the JSON elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
$object = json_decode($json);
```

This will create an object which you could then access the properties of like such..

```
echo $object->whatever;
```

Or you can use json_decode like this:

```
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

This create an array which you can access the indiviual keys of like so..

```
echo $array['whatever'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP's json_decode() function should satisfy this. In your first call, you pass TRUE as second parameter, so the function returns an associative array. The PHP manual page illustrates this difference:

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

These two calls to var_dump will output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
["a"] => int(1)
["b"] => int(2)
["c"] => int(3)
["d"] => int(4)
["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
["a"] => int(1)
["b"] => int(2)
["c"] => int(3)
["d"] => int(4)
["e"] => int(5)
}
```

In either of these cases you can access the individual elements:

```
$json       = '{"url":"stackoverflow.com","rating":"useful"}';

$jsonAsObject   = json_decode($json);
$jsonAsArray    = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo $jsonAsObject->url . " is " . $jsonAsArray['rating'];
```

This will output:

```
stackoverflow.com is useful
```

Answer (score 0):

You use an Object oriented dot.notation to access variable names. Try something like this:

```
alert($json_output->varName);
alert($json_output['varName']);
```